# Open LWC component in a subtab using Aura (workspace API)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura-id, workspaceapi

Considering the fact that LWC does not support workspace API, I have been trying to implement subtab opening feature by wrapping my LWC in a parent aura component. I have utilized workspace API for opening subtab. Subtab opens up by clicking on action button on record page but LWC does not display expected output. Adding my aura and LWC code for reference. Any help is highly appreciated.
[image: Error]

AuraComponent:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,
                        forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,
                        force:appHostable,
                        flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                        flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                        force:hasRecordId,
                        force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="isaura" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.openTabWithSubtab}" /></aura:component>
```

AuraController:

```
({
openTabWithSubtab : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId"); // Record ID
    var isaura = component.get("v.isaura");
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");        
    var navService = component.find("navService");
    
    var pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__component',
        attributes: {
            componentName: 'c__lwcChildcomponent',
        },
        state: {
            "c__recordIdCustomer": recordId
        }
    };
    component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);  
    /** OPEN My PLan Lightning component in subtab **/

    workspaceAPI.openTab({
        url: '/lightning/r/Account/'+recordId+'/view',
        focus: true
    }).then(function(response) {
        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: response,
            pageReference: pageReference,
        })
        .then(function(subTabId) {
            console.log('this is id of subtab: '+subTabId);
            // the subtab has been created, use the Id to set the label
            workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                tabId: subTabId,
                label: "Promotion Codes"
            });
              workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                  tabId: subTabId,
                  icon: "standard:timesheet",
                  iconAlt: "Focused Tab"
              });
              workspaceAPI.setTabHighlighted({
                  tabId: subTabId,
                  highlighted: true,
                  options: {
                      pulse: true,
                      state: "success"
                  }
              })
              workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                  tabId: response,
                  includeAllSubtabs: true
              });
          });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

})

lwcChildcomponent.html

```
<template>
    <h2>Child Component</h2>
    <p>{recordId}</p>
    ****Hello from lwc**** 
</template>
```

lwcChildcomponent.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class myclass extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
 @api recordId;

}
```

lwcChildcomponent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```